# UIBezierPath with random shaped border in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgcontext

I am drawing a `UIBezierPath` on a `CGContext` using Swift 3.0. I need the path to have random shaped border, i.e. outline - like the blue path in this image:

[image]

I haven't found anything in `UIBezierPath` that can help to do that. Could this be done using `CGPattern` or even `CGPath` ?

Comment: Are you talking about the blue or black part of the image?

Comment: what I have found till now is to draw an irregular-shaped image on the context at each touched point in 'touchesMoved'. This draws something like the above image but not exactly the same.